# How you pass variable inside [routerlink]

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

I need to pass current `userId` to `routerlink` in `borrow_list component`

The way i declare `userId` in `borrow_list component`

```
userId: number;
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private bookService: BookService,
     private route: ActivatedRoute, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }



ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = this.authService.decodedToken.nameid;
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.books = data['books'].result;
      this.pagination = data['books'].pagination;
    });
    this.borrowParam = 'loan';
    console.log(this.userId); // this one return 26
  }
```

Then i tried to pass `userId` to another component using `routerlink`

```
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let b of books" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-2">
    <app-book-card [book]="b"></app-book-card>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]=" 
     ['/browse/book/',this.userId,'/content/', b.id]" style="width: 75px">Read 
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it seem not working, no error but it direct me back to Home page

When i try to hard code the link and it work as intended i.e

```
[routerLink]="['/browse/book/26/content/', b.id]"
```

My `routes.ts`

```
{path: 'browse/book/:id/content/:bookId', component: Book_contentComponent, resolve: {book: BookContentResolver}}
```

I think i did it wrong somewhere?

Comment: Just try using: `<button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]=" 
     ['/browse/book/', userId, '/content/', b.id]" style="width: 75px">Read 
    </button>`. See there is no `this` with userId, give a try.

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]=" ['browse', 'book', userId, 'content', 
b.id]" style="width: 75px">Read </button>
```

Every path segment is an element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

When in template, variables are automatically taken from the underlying component. So you don't need to put `this` to access member variables.

In your code, you just need `userId` instead of `this.userId`, giving:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]=" 
 ['/browse/book/', userId,'/content/', b.id]" style="width: 75px">Read 
</button>
```

**Note**: not a good practice to put `style` inline in your HTML.

Comment: Tried still have the same problem

Comment: are you sure `this.userId` actually has the right value? Try `console.log(this.userId);` at the end of `ngOnInit`.